# Selenium - newbie getting older version to work before migration

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, selenium, selenium-rc

I am working on a project in which it makes use of an older version of Selenium - v0.9-2 server.  I will be migrating to the newest version but first require to get this version working  first and of course understand what it is doing.  This is my first time using this framework

So, I am running under Eclipse Indigo using Java 1.6 and FF V9

I have two eclipse launch files which are used to launch the server and then the test.

All test extends our customized BaseTestCase class.

BaseTestCase does nothing more then set up things for the tests.

Here is the configuration setting that are being used

```
    private static String TEST_SERVER = "localhost";
    private static int TEST_SERVER_PORT = 5555;
//  private static String TEST_BROWSER = "*firefox c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
    private static String TEST_BROWSER = "*custom C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe -firefoxProfileTemplate C:/temp/selenium-profile";
    public static String TARGET_URL = "http://w7001lt8001prd:9080";
    private static String TARGET_ROOT_PATH = "apps/gtgo.html";
```

Making use of the second TEST_BROWSER setting I was able to now bring up FF but the test are still not executing.

In the setup method of the this class we call Selenium this way:

```
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium(TEST_SERVER, TEST_SERVER_PORT,TEST_BROWSER, TARGET_URL);
    selenium.start();
```

There is a method that is used to open the root page - which will then make use of the TARGET_ROOT_PATH

When I launch the server here is the output:

```
(server.SeleniumServer               565 ) Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.4-b02
(server.SeleniumServer               566 ) OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
(server.SeleniumServer               686 ) v0.9.2-SNAPSHOT [2001], with Core v0.8.3-SNAPSHOT [1875]
(http.HttpServer                     684 ) Version Jetty/5.1.x
(util.Container                      74  ) Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
(util.Container                      74  ) Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
(util.Container                      74  ) Started HttpContext[/,/]
(http.SocketListener                 204 ) Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
(util.Container                      74  ) Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@77df38fd
```

When I launch the test suite here is the output

```
(util.Credential                     60  ) Checking Resource aliases
(server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler 391 ) Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*custom C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe -firefoxProfileTemplate C:/temp/selenium-profile, http://w7001lt8001prd:9080] on session null
(server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler 586 ) Launching session 605798
```

FF starts up but I am shown a single tab which states that it is unable to connect: Firefox can't establish a connect to the server w7001lt8001prd:9080

Any direction on what is going on here to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out in order to get this to all work, the correct version of FireFox need to be installed - 4.0 or less along with placing the Firefox home directory into the path.  Once that is done I am now able to run the test suite.  Next step - migrate to version 2.